# Organisation of tests for many application

Tags: python

We have a project python with a share-library (let's call it `shared`) and many "small" application (micro services) that use it (let's call them `app1` `app2`).
Those applications have many scripts and some python code too.

Code organization was like this:

```
/src
  app1/
    start.sh
    app1.py
  app2/
    start.sh
    app2.py
  shared/
    organisation/
      __init__.py
      utils.py
```

We want to make some test (obviously)

so we tried something like this:

```
/src
  app1/
    start.sh
    app1.py
    tests.py
  app2/
    start.sh
    app2.py
    tests.py
  shared/
    organisation/
      __init__.py
      utils.py
    tests/
      test_utils.py
```

Our problem is:
* it's a pain to launch all test; we go in each directory and launch tests (manually!).
* our build process took every app folder and send it to production (it's ******* ugly!)
So we wanted to make it better !

And we came with this

```
/src
  app1/
    start.sh
    app1/
      app1.py
    tests/
      tests.py
  app2/
    start.sh
    app2/
      app2.py
    tests/
      tests.py
  shared/
    organisation/
      __init__.py
      utils.py
    tests/
      test_utils.py
```

Now the CI copy only the good folder and not the tests folder, but pytest do not like our organization (there some conflicts in names).

So we came up with this:

```
/src
  app1/
    start.sh
    app1/
      app1.py
  app2/
    start.sh
    app2/
      app2.py
  shared/
    organisation/
      __init__.py
      utils.py
/tests/
  app1/
    tests.py
  app2/
    tests.py
  organisation/
    test_utils.py
```

But `pytest` do not like it either...

My question is: 
* is their a good way to organize this kind of projects (many app, and shared libs?)

Note:
* we want to keep only one git and not bother with submodules / subtree etc..
* we do not want to use pypi and Pipenv to manage our internal dependencies
* we would like to have one code coverage for all the code (and not one for each application / lib) so we want one launch of `pytest`.

Thanks

---

Our solution:
We get back too:

```
/src
  app1/
    start.sh
    app1/
      app1.py
    tests/
      tests.py
  app2/
    start.sh
    app2/
      app2.py
    tests/
      tests.py
  shared/
    organisation/
      __init__.py
      utils.py
    tests/
      test_utils.py
```

And launch test with:

```
py.test src/app1 src/app2 src/shared
```

And it seams to work well enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
python -m unittest discover -v /my/base/dir "*_test.py"
```

Now this will search all the files with `_test.py` suffix and run tests, even if you have tests in nested dirs.

Comment: The problem (I did not tell) is that we use relative imports in our tests.
That mean we can't launch every `test.py` as a standalone script (wich was what we used to do).